# Refresh a form that contains DLookup values

Tags: vba, ms-access

I want to refresh a form that contains a Private Sub Form_Open with DLookup values.

It only updates the fields in this form after I closed and reopened the form.

These options did not work:

```
Me.Recalc
Me.Requery
Me.Refresh
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Form_Open` is an event handler that is executed the first time the form is opened. To my knowledge there is no way to trigger the event a second time without closing the form first.

You can explicitly call `Form_Open` directly, though. If you want to do this from a context where you cannot access this private sub, you should move the `DLookup`s to another (public) sub that is then called from `Form_Open`. Use that sub to refresh the form after it was opened.